# Error Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap when using setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)

Tags: android, android-widget

Im using a custom layout and at times I enable and disable the drawing cache.

The only gotcha is that I'm developing for min APIVersion 9, but anything below 14 produces the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@41ee8a88
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1026)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1065)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13620)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13589)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13591)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13589)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13710)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2211)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.drawSoftware(ViewRootImpl.java:2281)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2177)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2045)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1854)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
E/AndroidRuntime( 6954):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
```

I'm not directly using any bitmaps, I'm really not sure what the problem is.  If I take out the line setting `setDrawingCacheEnabled(false)`, things work, but I'd like to keep it in for performance.

Comment: Use a MAT Analyzer to find memory leaks.
www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk. The guy shows how to use mat to find memory leaks

Comment: mat doesn't indicate anything obvious. This is a very small app, one custom layout with a background and a main layout with a button on.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed the problem.  I was using existing code, but I don't think it had been fully implemented to use the drawing cache.  I thought that setting the drawing cache on an existing view was it, and that the view would deal with using the cache for you, but it seems like you actually need to implement it.

I added this to my custom layout and the problem has dissapeared;

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if (cache != null && !cache.isRecycled()) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(cache, x, y, null);
    } else {
        super.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```